# Python can't find ssh binaries in Windows using subprocess.run, even with full path to ssh.exe

Tags: python, windows, openssh

When I run `scp.exe` in powershell, it shows the usage. But python tells that file doesn't exist testing with `os.path.isfile("C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\scp.exe")`. All my scripts that calls scp through `subprocess.run` were working before. Now it results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Alyson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\Alyson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Alyson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado
```

The only things I did recently is install a Windows Update (KB4537759, KB4532693) and update Python from 3.7 to 3.8. I even tried to pass `shell=true` to `subprocess.run`.

[scp existance tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkqJa.png)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what caused the problem. It is the architecture version of Python.

My Windows is 64-bit. I've downloaded the embedded version of both 32-bit and 64-bit. The 64-bit version found the scp.exe executable as shown below:

- MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel):

```py
PS C:\Users\Alyson\Documents\0\Xpriment\python32> .\python                                    Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 22:39:24) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>>> import shutil; shutil.which("scp")
>>>
```

- MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64):

```py
PS C:\Users\Alyson\Documents\0\Xpriment\python64> .\python                                            Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> import shutil; shutil.which("scp")
'C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\scp.EXE'
>>>
```

[image: print of results]

The Python I installed before was 64-bit. Bothered with the message in Visual Studio Code that the interpreter was not installed, I clicked the linked and reinstalled the interpreter, but the link pointed to a 32-bit version.